# Laravel Eloquent Model Dynamic Stored Properties from and to a single serialized field

Tags: laravel, serialization, eloquent

Using Eloquent L5.1

I'd like to not have to define a set of properties for a model. Instead having everything stored within the database as a serialized column.

In other words any property that is set to this model should before save be removed from the object and added to an array to be serialized and then saved in db to a "data" column.

In turn after retrieving the object from db the model should be hydrated with the de-serialized parameters from the data column.

I could override a good number of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model methods to accomplish this and I'm willing to do so, was curious if anyone had an example of this.

---

An example of this might be for configuration objects that have virtually unlimited unknown values that have multiple itterations for different objects or for different users.

Comment: Do you want to store all the data as json in data column, and when you retrieve the data It should be decoded, Is this you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put these accessors and mutators in your Model:

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    public function getDataAttribute($data)
    {
        return collect(json_decode($data,true));
    }

    public function setDataAttribute($data)
    {
        $data = (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) ? json_encode($data) : $data;
        return $this->attributes['data'] = $data;
    }   
}
```

Now when you can pass data as json string, array or object

```
YourModel::create(['data'=>'{"working":"ok"}']);
YourModel::create(['data'=>['working'=>'ok']]);
```

It will work in all three cases.

Comment: pretty good I was looking to be able to:
 $yourModel->key = "value"
$yourModel->save();
$yourModel->toArray(); // 'key' => 'value'

Comment: @ajameswolf If it solved your problem, please mark it as right answer.